# Draw a border line for a specific width

Tags: html, css

I want to bring my Sketch file to HTML/CSS in the browser.

How can I implement the white line just between the small and big text, as shown in the image below?

[image: White line I want to work on]

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don't want to include any additional `html element` then you can use `pseduo element:after`.

```
h2:after {
  display:block;
  content:" ";
  width: 80px;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uanb6drp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty div with a bottom border & custom width, which is of cleaner and shorter code:

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
#mydiv {
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    width: 33%;
}
#myline {
    height: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
A div:
<div id="mydiv"></div>
A horizontal line:
<hr id="myline" />

That's 4 lines for the HR and 2 for the div, and that's without making the hr align to the left.
```

If you don't want to add another element you can use `::after` on any element - just make it have `display: block` and set the color, width, height etc. similar to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag `<hr>` and him specify needed width, height,color...